# High Performance MySQL

Tags: mysql

A coworker handed me a copy of High Performance MySQL by Jeremy D. Zawodny and Derek J. Balling. The book (published by O'Reilly) has a publish date of 2004. I haven't found an updated edition. My question is how reliable is the information at this time?

For example, the author's make the statement "MySQL will only ever use one index per table query". Is this still true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd edition is available and was released on June 26, 2008.. the one on [amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101716) is cheaper than the OReilly direct unless you have some extra coupons.

Major additions include:

- Emphasis throughout on both performance and reliability
- Thorough coverage of storage engines, including in-depth tuning and optimizations for the InnoDB storage engine
- Effects of new features in MySQL 5.0 and 5.1, including stored procedures, partitioned databases, triggers, and views
- A detailed discussion on how to build very large, highly scalable systems with MySQL
- New options for backups and replication
- Optimization of advanced querying features, such as full-text searches
- Four new appendices

Answer (score 1):

Second Edition is available at http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101718 circa 2008. Not much has changed though, be warned - It does cover some changes for MySQL 5.0 and 5.1.